# How can I deploy this code on AWS Lambda and generate a csv?

Tags: aws-lambda

I want to deploy this code in lambda and run it every hour to generate a CSV. How can I do that and what are the steps for it?

```html
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse
import boto3
import datetime
import re
import csv
import random
import pandas as pd


now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
start = '2022-12-01'
end = '2022-12-20'
str = ' 00:00'

 

# to use a specific profile e.g. 'dev'
session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='dev')
cd = session.client('ce', 'eu-west-2')

results = []

token = None
while True:
    if token:
        kwargs = {'NextPageToken': token}
    else:
        kwargs = {}
    data = cd.get_cost_and_usage(TimePeriod={'Start': start, 'End':  end}, Granularity='MONTHLY', Metrics=['UnblendedCost'], Filter={  "And": [    {"Dimensions": {"Key": "SERVICE","Values": ["Amazon Relational Database Service", "Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud - Compute"]}},    {"Tags": {"Key": "Name", "Values": ["qa-mssql"]}},  ]}, GroupBy=[{'Type': 'TAG', 'Key': 'app'}, {'Type': 'TAG', 'Key': 'Name'}], **kwargs)
    results += data['ResultsByTime']
    token = data.get('NextPageToken')
    if not token:
        break


def data():    
    
    print(','.join(['date', 'teams', 'resource_names', 'Amounts','resource_type' ]))
    for result_by_time in results:
        for group in result_by_time['Groups']:
            amount = group['Metrics']['UnblendedCost']['Amount']
            resource_type = 'mssql'
            value = print(result_by_time['TimePeriod']['End'].__add__(str),',',','.join(group['Keys']).replace ("app$", "").replace("Name$", "") ,  ',', amount, ',', resource_type,)
    return value
data()
```

I am pretty new to lambda and want to know the basics step by step approach to it.

Answer (score 0):

Deploying your code to lambda, package it as zip file and deploy it directly to function from console or upload to s3 and then refer the path in lambda.

If your code doesn't require any dependencies which are not part of lambda environment, you can directly edit the code in console and save it.

Add trigger to the lambda with "CloudWatchEvent Schedule"

Refer this aws [doc1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-package.html#gettingstarted-package-zip) and this [doc2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-function-zip.html)